# some confusion about open set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Is  $[0, \frac{1}{2})$  is open  in $[0,1]$ ?

My attempt  :  For  open    it complement must be  closed  . Now $ [0,1] - [0, \frac{1}{2})= [\frac{1}{2} , 1)$  which is not closed in  $[0,1]$

similarly we can  said that  $[0, \frac{1}{2})$ is also not open in $\mathbb{R}$

Is its  true ?

Comment: Note that $[0,1]\setminus \left[0,\frac12\right) = \left[\frac12,1\right]$, which *is* closed in $[0,1]$. You made an error.

Comment: you could say $[0,\frac12)$ is the intersection of $(-\infty,\frac12)$, which is open in the usual topology on $\mathbb R$, and $[0,1]$, so it is open in the subspace topology on $[0,1]\subset\mathbb R$

Comment: When we use the metric restricted to $[0,1]$, $[0,\frac12) = B(0, \frac12)$ a metric ball and hence open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $[0,1]\setminus\left[0,\frac12\right)=\left[\frac12,1\right]$, which *is* closed in $[0,1]$ (since it is a subset of $[0,1]$ and a closed subset of $\mathbb R$), $\left[0,\frac12\right)$ is open in $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

Easier to simply note $(-\frac 12,\frac 12)$ is open in $\mathbb R$ so $(-\frac 12,\frac 12)\cap [1,1] = [0,\frac 12)$ is open in $[0,1]$.

But the complement of $[0,\frac 12) = [\frac 12, 1]$.  I do not see why you forgot to include the $1$. and that is closed in $[\frac 12, 1]$ (it is closed in $\mathbb R$) so $[0,\frac 12)$ is open in $[0,1]$

It is worth noting that had your space been $[0,1)$ then the complement of $[0,\frac 12)$ *is* equal to $[\frac 12,1)$.  And $[\frac 12,1) = [\frac 12, \infty) \cap [0,1)$ is *closed* in $[0,1)$ and $[0,\frac 12)$ is open in $[0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that the open sets of $[0,1]$ are precisely of the form $U \cap [0,1]$ for some open set $U$ of $\Bbb R.$ Now take any $a \in (-\infty,0)$ and consider the open interval $I=\left ( a,\frac 1 2 \right)$ in $\Bbb R.$ Since any open interval in $\Bbb R$ is an open set in $\Bbb R$ so $I$ is an open set in $\Bbb R.$ Now only observe that $\left [0, \frac 1 2 \right ) = I \cap [0, 1]$ and then you are through.